# Error: Javascript identifier already been declared inside switch when deconstructing variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I've a switch for a redux reducer, and I'm having trouble with deconstructing a javascript object which is the payload.

**Code file:**

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_FIELD:
      let { text, field } = action.payload;

      let newState = { ...state };
      newState.inputs[field].content = text;

      return newState;
    case FOCUS_CREDENTIALS_FIELD:
      let { field } = action.payload;

      let newState = { ...state };
      newState.inputs[field].focused = true;

      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Anyway to fix this without having to use different variable names?

Comment: You just need to make your `case` clauses into blocks by adding `{ }` around the bodies.

Comment: Thanks this worked!

Comment: Teebo isn't this updating the state? I'm just copying the object to avoid changing it directly, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`let` variables are block scoped and the entire `switch` body is one block.

You can move your deconstructive assignment line to the start:

```js
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
   let { text, field } = action.payload;
   let newState = { ...state };
   
    case CHANGE_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_FIELD:
      newState.inputs[field].content = text;

      return newState;
    case CHANGE_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_FIELD:
      newState.inputs[field].focused = true;

      return newState;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This works if you have (roughly) the same logic for each of those. And in this case you do - you always want `field` from `action.payload` and you sometimes need `text`. So, if you take both, you can use one or both as appropriate. In addition, `newState` is always `{ ...state }` and as a `let` variable, you also need to avoid re-declaring it.

Another alternative is to put each `case` into a block:

```js
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case CHANGE_LOGIN_CREDENTIALS_FIELD: {
      let { text, field } = action.payload;

      let newState = { ...state };
      newState.inputs[field].content = text;

      return newState;
    }
    case FOCUS_CREDENTIALS_FIELD: {
      let { field } = action.payload;

      let newState = { ...state };
      newState.inputs[field].focused = true;

      return newState;
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This makes each `case` a self-contained block, so you avoid clashes of `let` variables between them.